# StringBuffer toString() not printing anything

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

This code snippet doesn't print anything in jdk 1.8. Why so ?

```
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        sb.append(String.valueOf(i));
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Looks okay to me.  Have you tried stepping through it?

Comment: I suspect it's because you're trying to print a really long string on a single line, and it's just not showing in your terminal. Try `10` instead of `10000`.

Comment: It works fine for me even with 10k loops

Comment: @JoséMª ye, but maybe he works in environment when it can't print String that long, maybe Rapsberry Pi or something like that

Comment: @Whatzs or even just the eclipse terminal. I'm sure I've seen questions about this issue before.

Comment: @Whatzs Yes, you are right. I tested it in NetBeans 8.2 terminal

Comment: Your snippet is okay, it does not print the buffer on my eclipse neither, only if I add something on append, like: `sb.append(" i: " + String.valueOf(i))`  (does not work with only whitespaces or empty string).

Comment: One thing, though. Don't use `StringBuffer`, use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you printing a very long string, the issue here is with Eclipse. Even after removing the limit of console it is not printing anything (going to raise bug on eclipse forum soon).

However the other IDE's like NetBeans and IntelliJ printing perfect.